# toggle class not working when i give same name to css and jquery

Tags: jquery

i add the same name for css class and jquery class.if try to use toogle class already added css property remove from the respective tag.and then click button it's not working what's problem toogle class

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jquery</title>
        <script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
       $(".test").toggleClass("test");     
        });
    });    
    </script>
        <style>
            .test{font-size: 20px; background-color: blue;color: yellow}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="test">mani</h1>
        <h2 class="test">sankar</h2>

        <button>click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you remove the `test` class (via the first call to `toggleClass('test')`, your `$('.test')` selector will no longer be able to find that element

Comment: toggle class working in add and remove order y remove and add not working.if i am using differnt name reverse order working???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should be like this

```
$(".test").toggleClass("test2");
```

In case you want to remove the class `.test` then you can try this,

```
$(".test").toggle(function(){
$(this).removeClass(".test");
}
```

OR by another approach

```
$(".test").removeClass("test").addClass('test2');
```

UPDATED ANSWER

```
 $("button").click(function(){
   if ($("h1, h2 ").hasClass("test")){
   $("h1, h2 ").removeClass("test"); 
      } else {$("h1, h2 ").addClass("test");}    
    });

});
```

Comment: i want add/remove test class only.y it's not working

Comment: we can remove it using removeClass.but i want  remove/add the same test class plz ans me

Comment: plz forget test2 class.i want only remove/add same (test) class

Comment: ok you just want to remove/add test class on the click event, am i right?

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the updated JQuery, it appears to be working as you want.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2NR8c/

```
<style>
.test{font-size: 20px; background-color: blue;color: yellow}
.test2{font-style:italic}
</style>
<body>
        <h1 class="test">mani</h1>
        <h2 class="test">sankar</h2>

        <button>click me</button>
</body>

$(document).ready(function(){
 var toggle = $(".test");
   $("button").click(function(){
   $( toggle ).toggleClass("test");     
});
});
```

Comment: i know that but i want remove/add test css class. i am using test2 for another tag only

Comment: may i know reason for already not working.now it's working plz explain me

Comment: I just added the variable which retrieves the css class from the DOM. Please accept the answer it if is working for you.

Comment: it's ok.but y my code isn't working.do u know reason?plz tell me

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what was wrong with your code. My only guess is that on the second click, the page is already in the "document ready" state so javascript was unable to find the .test class. By wrapping it in $() that allowed JQuery to search the DOM for that object then find it and use it. Hopefully this will help you understand http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it will work.

```
$(".test").toggleClass("test2");
```